# Way to make collection in a form like a choice with Symfony2

Tags: database, forms, symfony

I'm trying to make a form for a House entity in which the user can add many shops arond the house and foreach the distance between the house and the shop.

So the database looks like this:

### house

- id
- ...

### house_rel_shop

- id
- fk_house
- fk_shop
- distance

### shop

- id
- lib
- ...

So it looks like a many to many but it isn't (because of the distance).

I want to add to the house form all the shops and foreach shop:

[Checkbox] [ShopName] [distanceTextBox]

Then the house_rel_shop contains only selected shop, but ALL the shops are listed in the form.

To make sense with the database structure, the symfony form type should be "collection" (because it is a one to many relation), but i can figure out the way to do this.

Any idea / clue of how to do this ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I believe I have solved a similar problem; I was creating Employees, which belong to a Company that is chosen from a dropdown. Depending on the Company chosen, a Department dropdown would then only show Departments that belong to that Company, which have a many to many relationship, joined by a company_department table. Is this the functionality you are after?

Comment: It seems like the Compagny<->Departements relation except that in your case the form field type is "entity" (with multiple option) because you have a many-to-many relation. In my problem, i want to make the same form BUT with the distance textbox added. So it can't be a many-to-many anymore, and for one-to-many relation, symfony use collections.